# Componente filho, retornar para componente pai REACT

Tags: javascript, react

Tenho o seguinte modal:

```
<Modal dialogClassName="clientes-modal" show={this.state.show} className="modal fade">
    <Modal.Header className="bg-new">
        <h4 ><i className="fa fa-plus"/> Novo Cliente</h4>
        <h4 className="x-button" onClick={() => {this.fechar()}}>
          <i className="fa fa-times"/>
        </h4>
     </Modal.Header>
     <Modal.Body className="center margin-bottom-15">
         <Cadastro/>
     </Modal.Body>
</Modal>
```

O que eu preciso, é que o componente `<Cadastro/>` feche esse modal quando executar uma função `PHP`, como posso fazer isso?

> `<Cadastro/>`

```
render(){
    return(
        <div className="content novo">
            <Alerta ref={(ref)=>this.alerta = ref} />
            <Form id='testeForm' 
                 action={_P_URL_ + 'cliente/gravar_cadastro'} 
                 erro={erro => this.erro(erro)}>
                <h3 className="nova_titulo">Novo</h3>
                <hr/>

                <Row>
                    <Input label="*Nome" nome="nome" md="3" />
                    <InputCpf label="*CPF" id="cpf" nome="cpf" md="3" />
                    <InputData label="Data de nascimento" nome="nascimento" md="3" />
                    <Input label="RG" nome="rg" md="3" />
               </Row>

               <Row>
                   <InputPhone label="*Telefone" nome="telefone" md="6"/>
                   <Input label="E-mail" nome="email" md="6" />
               </Row>

               <h4 className="titulo">Endereço</h4>
               <hr/>
               <Endereco />
               <ButtonSubmitForm><i className="fa fa-check"/> Gravar</ButtonSubmitForm>
           </Form>
        </div>
)}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você passa a função `fechar` da modal pra dentro do `<Cadastro>`. Algo como

`<Cadastro onSubmit={() => this.fechar()} />`

Daí no cadastro você invoca essa função onde precisar, pegando do props

`... this.props.onSubmit() ...`

Answer (score 3):

Você pode passar uma **arrow function** como parâmetro nesse componente "Cadastro" pra alterar a variavel do state "show". Por exemplo:

```
<Cadastro onClose={() => this.setState({show: false})}/>
```

Ai quando essa função no "Cadastro" que tem que fechar o "Modal", você pode usar esse parâmetro "onClose" nela do sequinte modo:

```
this.props.onClose && this.props.onClose();
```

Fazendo desse modo ali, primeiro você vai ver se existe algo nesse parâmetro "onClose" e depois chamar a função que está nesse parâmetro.